# If $X$ is a finite $G$-set and $|g|=p^n$ with $n\ge 1$, show that $|X|=|X^{g^{p^{n-1}}}|\pmod{p^n}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a group and let $X$ be a finite $G$-set.
> Assume that $g\in G$ is of finite order $p^n$, where $p$ is a prime number and $n\ge 1$.
> Let $h=g^{p^{n-1}}$.
> Show that $|X|=|X^h|\pmod {p^n}$,
> where $X^h=\{x\in X: h\cdot x=x\}$.

Using the identity
$$
|X|=|X^h|+\sum_i [\langle h \rangle : \text{Stab}_{\langle h \rangle}(x_i)]
$$
where no $x_i\in X$ is fixed by all elements in $\langle h \rangle$,
we derive that $|X|=|X^h|+p\cdot \#\text{non-trivial $\langle h \rangle$-orbits}$.
It remains to show that the number of non-trivial $\langle h \rangle$-orbits is divisible by $p^{n-1}$.
I struggle to proceed.
If we apply Burnside's lemma, we then need to show that $p^n$ divides $\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} |X^{h^m}|$,
which I have no idea about.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need Burnside's Le. a. $h$ has order $p$. The stabilizer subgroups in your sum are all trivial. Now look at your expression modulo $p$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeah, but the problem requires modulo $p^n$.

Comment: Oops, right. Look at the action of $g$. Any element in any orbit of size less than $p^n$ will be fixed by $h$, so the only contributors to the sum are pieces of orbits of size $p^n$, hence they add up to a multiple of $p^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the action of $g$. Since $\langle h\rangle$ is contained in any nontrivial subgroup of $\langle g\rangle$, $h$ is contained in the stabilizer of any $x\in X$ whose orbit has fewer than $p^n$ elements. Thus, all those elements are in $X^h$. The remaining elements lie in orbits of size $p^n$, which get partitioned into orbits of size $p$ by $h$; these are the terms in the sum, which is therefore a multiple of $p^n$.